# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' - Python - OpenErp

Tags: python, function, orm, odoo

I need to read a field in an object, which is `purchase.order` , from another object `product.product` 
This field is a selection type field, so if this field has `si` is selected then do `_get_product_available_func(('done'))` which is a function already declared in `product.product`

This is the selection field in `purchase.order`

```
'sel_cert' : fields.selection([('si', 'Si'),('no','No')], 'Origen Certificado'),
```

And this the function which should "retrieve" that field from `product.product`

```
def desc_cert(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, field_args, context=None):
    obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')
    pids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('sel_cert', '=', 'si')])
    val = self._get_product_available_func(('done'))
    if pids == 'si':
            return val
```

The function which has `_get_product_available_func(('done))`

```
def _get_product_available_func(states, what):
    def _product_available(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
        return {}.fromkeys(ids, 0.0)
    return _product_available

_product_qty_available = _get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out'))
_product_certificado_qty = _get_product_available_func(('done',), ('in', 'out'))
_product_virtual_available = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned','done'), ('in', 'out'))
_product_outgoing_qty = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned'), ('out',))
_product_incoming_qty = _get_product_available_func(('confirmed','waiting','assigned'), ('in',))
```

So, i need to "execute" `_get_product_available_func(('done'))` in `product.product` when field `sel_cert` in `purchase.order` has the value `si` , but is giving me an error, here's the traceback in openerp server:

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 197, in execute
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 3604, in read
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 3724, in _read_flat
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20130726-231403\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\fields.py", line 1139, in get
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Perhaps i should call `_product_qty_available` instead in `_get_product_available_func`?

Anybody could clarify this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message basically says that you used the `get` method on something that you expected to have that method (probably a dict) but that turned out to be just `None`. You should add some guards to your code that check whether your variables really are what you believe them to be...

Comment: Mmm i see, i'm going to try your answer now, seems like a didn't declared things the way they should be

Comment: The first code show 'undefined' on products menu, can't even access them, because of the 'pool' getting override in the current object (maybe), then i tried 2nd code and still get the attribute error, you say that maybe it's the 'dict' from the select type field? Maybe returning not what i expect?

Comment: New idea: `desc_cert(...)` will only return something if `pids == 'si'`. Try to return an alternative if `pids != 'si'`.

Comment: Also, you might want to check out this site: http://help.openerp.com/questions/

Comment: Thank you very much! But i think that this issue is maybe due to the fact that the selection field is 'none' by default, i mean it doesn't takes 'si' or 'no' by default, so maybe i should put one option in _defaults of the class and see what happens, i'll do what you advice me anyways and see what happens, thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More ideas:

Try this for once:

```
def desc_cert(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, field_args, context=None):
    obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')
    pids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('sel_cert', '=', 'si')])
    val = self._get_product_available_func(('done'))
    if pids == 'si':
            return val
    return 10
```

If we get an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'`, we know that the fault is indeed in the output of this function.

Another idea:

```
def desc_cert(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, field_args, context=None):
    obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')
    pids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('sel_cert', '=', 'si')])
    val = self._get_product_available_func(('done'))
    if pids.lower() == 'si':
            return val
```

Now pids may be "si" or "Si".

Comment: It is indeed in the output of the function, gonna try the other idea

Comment: With ´if pids.lower() == 'si':´ it gives me 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'' maybe, i think it's the _defaults thing i was commenting you, gonna try it tomorrow and see what happens, thank you very very much!

Comment: Well, at least we know now that `pids` is a list.

Comment: Yeah, thank you! :) if it gets very hard i'll try another solution, and that's all, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def desc_cert(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, field_args, context=None):
    obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')
    pids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('sel_cert', '=', 'si')])
    if pids == 'si':
        val = self._get_product_available_func(('done'))
        return val
```

Or this:

```
def desc_cert(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, field_args, context=None):
    if self.pool:
        obj = self.pool.get('purchase.order')
    pids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('sel_cert', '=', 'si')])
    val = self._get_product_available_func(('done'))
    if pids == 'si':
            return val
```